# Bayes: markov chain, serial connection, marginalization

Tags: markov-chains, bayes-theorem

Goal is to check if p(a) is unconditionally independent to p(c) in the markov chain - serial connection.

$$
p(a,b,c) = p(a) p(b|a) p(c|b)
$$
$$
p(a,c) = \sum_b p(a) p(b|a) p(c|b) = p(a) p(c|a) \neq p(a) p(c)
$$

How can the marginalization in the second equation be evaluated to $p(a) p(c|a)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That equality is justified by the following:

\begin{eqnarray*}
p(c\mid a) &=& \sum_b p(c\mid b,a)p(b\mid a) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(conditioning on $b$)} \\
&=& \sum_b p(c\mid b)p(b\mid a) \\
&& \text{(Markov property: given $b$ we know $a,c$ are conditionally independent)} \\
&& \\
\therefore\quad p(a)p(c\mid a) &=& \sum_b p(a)p(c\mid b)p(b\mid a).
\end{eqnarray*}